# Image from URL Code Ruby

Tags: ruby, image, web-crawler

I'm making a random cat picture cracker, and decided that Ruby was the best. This code,

```rb
require 'chunky_png'
require 'open-uri'

d=rand(2000)+1

url="http://www.placekitten.com/"
open('image.png', 'wb') do |file|
  file << open(url,d).read
end
```

This is probably a really easy fix, but I'm new to ruby.... I get this error when I run it

> > C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/2.0.0/open-uri.rb:146:in `open_uri': invalid access mode 200
> >     (URI::HTTP resource is read only.) (ArgumentError)
> >             from C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/2.0.0/open-uri.rb:688:in`open'
> >             from C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/2.0.0/open-uri.rb:34:in `open'
> >             from Kittens.rb:8:in`block in '
> >             from C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/2.0.0/open-uri.rb:36:in `open'
> >             from C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/2.0.0/open-uri.rb:36:in`open'
> >             from Kittens.rb:7:in `'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to get images from http://www.placekitten.com/, you should append width (if height is ignored, it is set to width as default) to the URL. However, in your code, you have put the random width at the position of the second parameter of `open`, which is intended to be the open mode (`r`, `w`, `a`, etc). That's why Ruby complains about "invalid access mode XXX", where XXX is the random code `d` you get at that time the script is executed.

```rb
require 'chunky_png'
require 'open-uri'

d=rand(2000)+1

url="http://www.placekitten.com/"
open('image.png', 'wb') do |file|
  file << open(url + d.to_s).read
end
```

BTW, it's a good site for Web UI designer :-)